# Sampling a datetime from lines for days and columns for hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix where lines represent days and columns represent hours. I am looking for resampling this data to have a datetime as index.

`DATES; H0;H1;H2;H3;... 
01/01/2013;...;...;...;...;... 
02/01/2013;...;...;...;...;...`

When I use the df.resample('H') function I get the following results. I want now match the columns value with the hours of each day to fill the values.

`2013-01-01 00:00:00 1.35882 
2013-01-01 01:00:00 NaN 
2013-01-01 02:00:00 NaN 
2013-01-01 03:00:00 NaN 
2013-01-01 04:00:00 NaN`

Does anyone please have an idea on how to proceed?

Thanks Alexis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming DATES is your index, this should work

```
df.stack()
```

If 'DATES' is not your index, you can set it this way

```
df.set_index('DATES').stack()
```

Note: This will not set time format to what is in your example

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer.
To assess my need I have done the following after stack.

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1['DATES'] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['DAYS'] + \
    relativedelta(hours=int(row['level_1']) - 1), axis=1)
df1 = df1.set_index('DATES')
```

Alexis